# Android text on image

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, textview

I am working on an android app and i am trying to achive the same functionality as seen here place text ontop of picture and on 0:43 - 0:50 the more text added the smaller it gets, anyone has an idea or guidance?
[In this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlzLubZtlQU) is the example of the functionality i am trying to achieve

Btw I thought about placing textview on imageview than programatically "print screen" the view - is that possible?

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know if its possible to take a "print screen" of a layout
>   programatically than export it to an image file ...

If you want an image of a `View` try using [`getDrawingCache`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28boolean%29) to get a `Bitmap` of the `View` which you can manipulate as you please.

> ... also my question is how to resize the text in case it's going out of
>   the imageview bounds

For this you can extend `ImageView` and override [`onLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to adjust the size of its `TextView` depending on its size.